# 100% Div with centered, fixed-width inner Div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I ran into a CSS problem where I need some advice. I have a 100% div that contains a fixed-width. On 27", everything looks fine - the yellow div is perfectly centered.

When I resize the window, the yellow fixed bar still is visible, but as soon as you scroll rightwards, the 100% div does not resize to the current width.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />    

    <style type="text/css">    

    #footer {
      background-color: #333333;
      color: #ffffff;
      margin-top: 35px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      padding-top: 15px;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0px;
      font-size: 90%;
    }    

    #inner {
      background-color: #feb400; 
      width: 960px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }    

    </style>    

  <body>
    <footer id="footer">
      <div id="inner">lorem ipsum div.</div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nghg4zd5/

I would like to have the black, 100%-div always beeing resized. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want the outer div to stay 100% then you should use `max-width` for your inner div - http://jsfiddle.net/nghg4zd5/1/

Comment: I am not getting your question. Please explain it what do you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you should use min-width style property in 100%div (like same inner width value)

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nandhakumarsri9/nghg4zd5/3)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a relative change affect a fixed change (in pixel). To achieve that, you need to set the inner div to have a relative width (i.e in percentage) to make it visible on the right stretch (as per your fiddle).

**For instance,**

```
#inner {
    background-color: #feb400;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 92%;
}
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nghg4zd5/2/)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your div width 100% you have to make its parent (containing div) here the body having a fixed width:

Try this for example:

```
body {
  width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `width:100%;` with a `max-width:960px;`

`#inner {
      background-color: #feb400; 
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 960px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }`